# How to get tweets from the twitter api on the client side without exposing tokens

Tags: javascript, twitter

The documentation is pretty vague as to which api should be used and what should be hidden. All of the API documentation seems to assume you'll be hiding the oauth token and be making the request from a private server. Is there anyway to request from the twitter API from the client side without exposing vulnerable keys? I'm just trying to display a few tweets from our account using our own formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to hit the Twitter API from client-side code, because the consumer key would become public in your code, and also because Twitter does not support CORS, so this will not work.

Two options:

- use publish.twitter.com to build a timeline widget that you can embed on your page
- build a server-side component to get the Tweets using the API, and then pass to your front-end for display (ensuring you follow the [Twitter Display Requirements](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/display-requirements))